# Firebase SignUp with Email/Password failing auth

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

**The Problem**

I've been using the same code setup for the past 2 years without a single issue.
I use the firebase/auth library to authenticate the user to access data stored in Realtime Database and then carry out my usual read/write operation.

When trying to authenticate the user using `signInWithEmailAndPassword` I get an error `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

The problem appeared the first time on 1st December. It started intermittently and then it completely stopped working. I'm using the same authentication functionality across my code in various functions and it fails everywhere therefore not related issue on specific function.

The **username** and **password** are correctly passed and validated and showing correctly in console.log and I believe the issue is around the auth parameter.

**My project specs:**

- react native 0.71.14
- Expo sdk 48
- Node JS v18.17.1
- Firebase 9.21.0

Steps:

1. `firebase.js` is the firebase config file
2. `main.js` is a typical function that I call to write a new post rating into my Realtime Database.
3. When I call `addRating` I try first to authenticate my user in firebase before submitting a change
4. The usual `signInWithEmailAndPassword` now fails on auth

```
// firebase.js - Its where I setup my firebase config

import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getDatabase } from 'firebase/database';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
 
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "********",
  authDomain: "********",
  databaseURL: "********",
  projectId: "********",
  storageBucket: "********",
  messagingSenderId: "********",
  appId: "********",
  measurementId: "********",
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig); 
 export const auth = getAuth();
 export const db = getDatabase();
 export const email = "********",
 export const password = "********",

// main.js - example function where I use firebase auth 
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth, db, email, password } from "../../util/firebase";

const addRating = async (  id, rating  ) => { 
    await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    console.log('auth: ',auth)
    console.log('email: ',email)
    console.log('password: ',password)

   .then((userCredential) => {     
        console.log('userCredential: ',userCredential)
        const user = userCredential.user;             
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log("addReviewRequest failing to log to firebase with: " + errorCode + " - " + errorMessage);
    });

... rest of the code not running
```

> Error: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

The logs are showing the following:

```
LOG: auth:  {"apiKey": "**********", "appName": "[DEFAULT]", "authDomain": "*********",
"currentUser": {"_redirectEventId": undefined, "apiKey": "********", "appName": "[DEFAULT]",
"createdAt": "1607606241646", "displayName": undefined, "email": "*********", "emailVerified": false, "isAnonymous": false,
"lastLoginAt": "1701525810098", "phoneNumber": undefined, "photoURL": undefined,
"providerData": [Array], "stsTokenManager": [Object], "tenantId": undefined, "uid": "*******"}}
 LOG  email:  *********
 LOG  password:  *********
```

Whenever I use * it means it's returning the correct values as expected, just masking sensitive data.
My understanding that the failures point is in .then((userCredential) in fact it doesn't go any further in showing the `console.log('userCredential: ',userCredential)`

Basically `userCredential` is now `undefined` every time for some reason.

I've already posted a new issue in [github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/7832) but wondering if anyone else is facing similar issues and found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your console logs are getting in the way of the promise returned by `signInWithEmailAndPassword` and the call to `then` on it:

```
    await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    console.log('auth: ',auth)
    console.log('email: ',email)
    console.log('password: ',password)

   .then((userCredential) => {
```

As it stands now, your code is trying to call `then` on the result of `console.log()`, which is always going to be `undefined`.  You can't call any  methods on `undefined`, which is what the error message is trying to tell you.

Remove those logs to make your code correctly call `then` on the promise:

```
    await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
   .then((userCredential) => {
```

Even better, since this code is an in `async` function, don't use then/catch callbacks at all, and instead simply `await` the promise instead. It doesn't really make sense to use then/catch methods in an async function like this.

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the console logs, I only added them afterwards to check if signInWithEmailAndPassword was getting the correct values. If I remove the logs nothing changes, I still get the same error. I've seen other people posting issues with considerable delays in getting user authenticated. Any idea as it shouldn't be any coding issues since I've not changed anything

Comment: Also removed the then/catch, same issue

Comment: Your updated code is still wrong, and the logs are definitely causing the error.  You don't use then/catch along with await.  You use await **instead of** then/catch callbacks.  I suggest taking some time to review how JavaScript promises work.

Comment: I found the issue, I was using another signInWithEmailAndPassword somewhere in the code that was causing a conflict however I'm using you code recommendation with ```await``` and ```.then```. The official firebase doc is not using a promise but I think you are right.